# I am not able to connect to my websocket server through Java websocket client

Tags: java, apache, java-websocket

I am not able to connect to my websocket server through Java websocket client.Please help!
Apache Tomcat 8.0.26 is being used
Getting exception as "java.io.IOException: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

Client Class
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

```
import javax.websocket.*;

@ClientEndpoint
public class WebSocketClient {
    private static Object waitLock = new Object();
    protected Session userSession = null;
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    private static void wait4TerminateSignal() {
        synchronized (waitLock) {
            try {
                waitLock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void Connect(String sServer) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            System.out.println("Connecting");
            WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient();
            userSession = container.connectToServer(webSocketClient, URI.create(sServer));
            wait4TerminateSignal();
            System.out.println("Connected");

        } catch (DeploymentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * register message handler
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Send a message.
     * 
     * @param user
     * @param message
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    public void SendMessage(String sMsg) throws IOException {
        userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(sMsg);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public void Disconnect() throws IOException {
        userSession.close();
    }
}
```